# vimrc, like exec but replaces current process (fork?)

Tags: key-bindings, bash, filesystem, multiple-files

Such as in the following code:

```
let cpath = getcwd()
let cfile = expand('%')
function Run_file_hopper(cpath, cfile)
    silent exec "! . ~/path/somescript.sh" a:cpath a:cfile                                                                                                                            
    redraw!
endfunction
nnoremap gh :call Run_file_hopper(cpath, cfile)<CR>
```

We can run a bash script from vim, with a shortcut. By runnin exec.
Exec runs the shell script, and once it closes, returns back to the original script.

But what I am wanting, is to replace the current process, with the process that exec is executing. Kinda like c's fork.

Is that possible?

---

From the comments:

I am trying to run a bash script from vim. I need to send to this bash
script the file and path I am in at the point of execution. The bash script
needs to do some logistics, and after that, run vim again. I am making a hopping
mechanism, where I can click for instance, `hh`. I will hop to another
file. Which file is determined by which file I clicked `hh` from. This
way I can hop between files that are coupled very quickly. I have it logged in a
file, which pathfiles should go to which pathfiles. The bash script accesses
that file to determine where to open vim next.

Right now it kinda works but after hopping, if I quit vim, I am now in a
vim instance which is a subprocess of the previous vim. So I enter the
parent vim process upon quitting vim. I would have wanted to hop over to that
other pathfile, using the logistics determined in the bash file and continue
unabated.

Comment: exec(ute) does not run the shell script. The bang (!) does. Execute is probably closer to stringly-typed eval in some langs: it takes a variable number of string arguments and interprets the whole thing as a vimscript command to execute. At any rate, what exactly do you want? Vim has jobs, which seem close to what you describe, but it’s hard to tell. Do you want to replace the vim process (why? Probably not possible anyway, since bang running an external command probably *is* a fork/exec/wait)? What is the *current process*?

Comment: Actually, reading your code sample, it's totally unclear to me what it is that you want to accomplish... You seem to mix up fork() and execute() but I think what you really want is neither... Can you elaborate on the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why do you need to use bash? Can't you just read your "next file" file from Vim and open the file directly? In fact, could you not just use the args list, buffer list or quickfix, and hop with `:n` `:bn` etc?

Comment: If the logic in your bask script is too complicated to reproduce in Vim, why not get your bash script to simply output the path of the next file, call it with `system()`, and then perform the jump within Vim?

Comment: yeah. im just really bad in vimscript and am always getting better in bash. and i can reuse my bash knowledge all the time but my vimscript knowledge is limited to only vim forever. so im trying to port as much functionality as i can out of vimscript in order to encourage reuse. both of my knowledge and code. i would also not know how to do that in vimscript. /:

Comment: for those reasons i think it would be useful knowledge, to know how to port functionality out of vim, into bash/python/whatever, effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than replacing the existing instance of Vim with a new process, why not edit your bash script to output the path of the next file instead of invoking Vim.

You can then grab the output with the [`system()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) function and ask Vim to edit this file directly:

```
:execute 'edit' system('. ~/path/somescript.sh')
```

Comment: it works but only once. the path that gets sent to the bash script remains the same. that can be solved with set autochdir

Comment: @john-jones I didn't read your sample code carefully enough. You can change the command-line you pass to `system()` to include parameters. e.g. `system('. ~/path/somescript.sh ' . a:cpath . ' ' . a:cfile)`